# Google cloud spatie/image deploy error, build do not complete

Tags: php, laravel, docker, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to deploy a php project via cloud run, but I keep getting the same error

```
  Problem 1
    - spatie/image is locked to version 1.10.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - spatie/image 1.10.1 requires ext-exif * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's exif extension.
  Problem 2
    - spatie/pdf-to-image is locked to version 2.1.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - spatie/pdf-to-image 2.1.0 requires ext-imagick * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's imagick extension.
  Problem 3
    - spatie/image 1.10.1 requires ext-exif * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's exif extension.
    - spatie/laravel-medialibrary 7.19.5 requires spatie/image ^1.4.0 -> satisfiable by spatie/image[1.10.1].
    - spatie/laravel-medialibrary is locked to version 7.19.5 and an update of this package was not requested.
```

I can't find not about this package, but it's an Laravel's deppendece, so I can't uninstall, I am using docker to make this deploy

```
FROM composer as build
WORKDIR /app 
COPY . /app
RUN composer install --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-progress --no-scripts --optimize-autoloader

FROM node:12 as node
COPY package.json ./ 
COPY yarn.lock ./ 
RUN yarn install
RUN npm install

FROM php:7.3-apache-stretch
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
EXPOSE 8080
COPY --from=build /app /var/www/html
COPY 000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf 
     RUN echo "Listen 8080" >> /etc/apache2/ports.conf && \     
     chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html && \     
     a2enmod rewrite

CMD service apache2 restart && bash
```

already tried:

- remove as required package (Continuous deployment has been set up, but your repository has failed to build and deploy.)
- php composer.phar require spatie/image-optimizer --ignore-platform-reqs
- composer require google/cloud-logging google/cloud-error-reporting
- update the package
- update the yarn and the npm

Comment: Does this works well in local?

Comment: Yes, build and run with php artisan serve

Comment: in my case in windows about installing spatie/medialibrary 11 when it want to install spatie/image 3.3.3 or 3.3.2 when it want to run test

error is :

filename is too long

my problem resolved with :

git config --system core.longpaths true   https://stackoverflow.com/a/77791986/308578

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was resolved by running install commands on a Linux(ubuntu) platform, nothing else changed, I don't even have sure yet why the error was happening

Answer (score 3):

You have to install required php extensions, in dockerfile, at line
`RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql`
add `exif`:
`RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql exif`

Installing image magick, may be complicated, see https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/105#issuecomment-563010422 or this script - https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer

Comment: I've  tried, but it returns ´Oops, something went wrong…
Continuous deployment has been set up, but your repository has failed to build and deploy.´ when I try to open the url of the deploy

Comment: I miss it first time, `RUN docker-php-ext-install` should be before `composer install`. You can check your dockerfile locally, try to run `docker build` in your dockerfile directory

Comment: Now it runs, but still needing the package that return the error to work

Comment: Please, show your Dockerfile and error output